# Question about meaning of "jump" and "jump-start"

Tags: word-meaning

> Kevin: I used to have the same problem with my old car.Did you check the battery?
>
> Mary: Yeah. It was dead in the morning. I called the mechanic to give my car a **jump**.
>
> Kevin: Well, I guess if you need to "jump-start" your car, you probably need to buy a new battery.
>
> Mary: What are you saying? I bought this battery just a couple of months ago. I don't think I should have a problem with it every second day.

Is it about just pushing a car forward physically or to get help from a battery from another car?

Comment: "Every second day" is usually said as "every _other_ day."

Comment: @J.R. I've actually heard it said both ways in native English conversations, often "second" is used to be more explicit about the frequency of an issue as "other" can be used to imply either explicitly "every second day" or colloquially to imply "frequent but irregular occurrence". That being said I have also come across "every second day" being used to imply "frequent" but to emphasise/exaggerate the frequency. Gotta love English!

Answer (score 2):

It's to get help from another car battery.
One would connect a good battery to the bad one using *jumper cables*, to make sure the battery is the problem.

I have not heard this term used for pushing a car to start it.

Comment: If the car doesn't have an automatic transmission, you can push the car, get it rolling down a hill, and then _pop the clutch_ to start it. More [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_start).

Comment: It's not surprising you've not heard this term used for pushing a car to start it. What J.R. describes above is called ***bump-starting*** (from the bump/jolt that happens when you engage the clutch).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've never heard the term "bump-starting", I've always heard that called "push-starting" or occasionally "slipping the clutch". Perhaps there's a regional difference? In any case, note this does not work on an automatic transmission.

Comment: Or to be technical, it could be any other source of power. There are some products on the market now that are stand-alone batteries you can carry around to jump-start your own or someone else's car. I've bought several and none of them hold a charge for more than a month or so, making them pretty useless, but it's a great idea if they can get the technology to work. I have a more useful gadget than you plug into the wall and then connect to a car to jump-start it. It's not a battery and it doesn't live in another car.

Comment: @Jay: If you live on a hillside and have a car with a dodgy battery, you might ***bump** start* it by just rolling down the hill - no ***push*** required. I use both about equally often. Mainly depending on whether anyone else has to push or not, but I do think ***bump*** can apply regardless, whereas a ***push*** usually requires a helper.

Comment: @Fumble et al. - The Wiki article I linked to listed at least 5 names for this technique, and that's probably not an exhaustive list.

Comment: @J.R.: Indeed. But I'm not sure I've ever heard any of ***clutch starting, popping the clutch, crash starting*** in the UK. I think they must all be at least primarily US terms. And as you point out, you can only bump start a manual transmission. US cars are normally automatics, but it's the reverse in the UK (which distinction was even more extreme until a decade or two ago) - so imho Brits have more right to name the procedure, since *we've always been the ones who need to do it most*.

Comment: @Fumble - I agree; it appears to be regional. I've heard it called "popping the clutch" all my life, but had never heard of "bump starting" until I read your answer. You should add "bump starting" to the Wikipedia page :^) As to your last comment, I don't see a need for a standard term – after all, we already have standard transmissions ;^)

Comment: I've also heard "popping the clutch". Never "clutch starting" or "crash starting".